# Query over a field which is deep inside MongoDB collection using array of possible options

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a `list` of `commentDocument` collection in `MongoDB` where each has the following structure:

```
{
    "commentName": "test comment",
    "outputs": {
        "extraDetails": [{
            "name": "My Own Comment",
            "amountPaidDetails": [{
                "paidService": "PhonePe",       // <--------HERE
                "usdAmount": 80,
            },{
                "paidService": "GooglePay",  // <--------HERE
                "usdAmount": 50,
            },{
                "paidService": "Cash",        // <--------HERE
                "usdAmount": 15,
            }]
        }]
    },
    "lastUpdateDate": {
        "$date": "2020-06-24T04:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "lastUpdatedBy": "michealJackson",
}
```

I have to write a MongoDB query passing a list of paidService names as input. And if the document from the DB has any of the paidServices from the list I've sent in the `allocatedAmound` list, the document should be present in the returned list of documents.

Eg: I pass list `['WalletCash', 'GooglePay', 'BankingCredits']`, the above document should be present because it has a document with a paidService `'GooglePay'`.

How to write the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "outputs.extraDetails.amountPaidDetails.paidService": {
        $in: [
          "WalletCash",
          "GooglePay",
          "BankingCredits"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VReBPG3F2Y5)

Comment: Or even, [`db.collection.find(...`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WsvVocpWKP8).